# tinyMCE (phplist plugin) fullscreen mode not displaying in full width

Tags: php, tinymce

I installed TinyMCE for my phplist but the fullscreen mode is not displaying in full width

[image]

I saw this line of code

```
<div id="mce_32" class="mce-tinymce mce-container mce-panel mce-fullscreen" hidefocus="1" tabindex="-1" style="visibility: hidden; border-width: 1px; width: 600px;">
```

The editor window only has 600px width. I changed it with 100% directly in browser console, it can display with full width. But I can't fix it by editing the css , and the plugin php config, or the javascript.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: try this: .mce-fullscreen{width:100% !important}

Comment: @noob it works , mark it as answer , thanks, i add .mce-fullscreen{width:100% !important}  in skin.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

.mce-fullscreen{width:100% !important}

Remember try to avoid using !important tag. 
Use it as less often as possible